# printf вывод в консоль длинного числа (с большой точностью) float

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток, подскажите как настроить компилятор или изменить код чтобы он выводил большое число (с большой точностью) с плавающей точкой не убирая цифры?

Вот собственно код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char string[] = "FuckYeah";

int main()
{
printf("%f\n", *(double*)string);
}
```

Как показала практика, код запущенный из-под разных компиляторов выводит число разной длины.
Например:
[Компилятор с сайта ideone.com или cpp.sh](http://ideone.com/HtYLGE) выведет в консоль число не обрезая его:
`634941928355238664703301556538757088234490620633221521060631490352699066770913322172609098633882733972770441183071593866097446888694984996051123410270173974499242719895307423437791973739342069760.000000`

На моем домашнем компьютере компиляторы выводит это же число, но уже обрезав его и в экспонентной форме:
`6.349419283552386647000000000000000000000e+194`

Comment: пробовали выводить `"%.20f"`?

Comment: О чем вообще можно говорить при таком вызове? Преобразовать указатель на строку в указатель на `double`, разыменовать, выводить как `float`...

Comment: @pavel да, пробовал по всякому и `"%.20f"` тоже
P.S. компилятор: Borland C++ Compiler version 5.5 бесплатный
или Dev-C++.
GCC выдает уже немного по другому: `634941928355238660000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00000000000000000000`

Comment: Кстати, фигня - никакой `double` такую точность не вытянет.

Comment: @Harry компиляторы с сайта [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/HtYLGE) вытягивают большое число, почему-то...

Comment: Тут что-то не то... Надо побитно поразбираться, что за хрень творится...

Comment: @Harry взял отсюда [9 интересных трюков на Си, с которыми вы раньше не сталкивались](https://tproger.ru/translations/9-clang-tricks/) и отсюда [deobfuscation...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992553/concept-behind-these-four-lines-of-tricky-c-code)